# Uploading images with question

Tags: support

Sorry if this is a dupe. I considered uploading an image with a question but the functionality is not working for me. The interface says "click here" but this seems to do nothing. I tried copying and pasting...

Operator error, most likely. Guidance appreciated.

Comment: The interface is (usually, barring beta-testing of new features) the same for all sites on the [se] network. For these type of questions (about the Stack Exchange network and interface) also consider consulting [meta.se] and asking there if searching doesn't yield a fix. For example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @hoc_age: Will do. Not sure why, but I have uploaded images to the bio and math sites with no problem. Maybe some time has passed...? Maybe security settings.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is indeed "operator error" :)  But no big deal! It's fun to learn new features of how to make questions and answers even more helpful and pleasant to read.

See [a Meta.SE question on adding images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). The interface has been changed/improved since then.

A number of different things could be at work... e.g.,

- Your browser (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari, ...)
- Your browser settings (dis/allow scripts, pop-ups, security settings)
- Your OS or interface (Linux, OS X, Windows, mobile browser, Stack Exchange app)
- Simply getting used to the interface. :)

Here's an example: link to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/103px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png as an image: click the "Add Image" button, then click "link from the web" link, then paste the URL, then click the "Add Picture" button. 
Result:

[image]

You could also manually type in the Markdown for an image, which looks something like...

```
![alternate mouseover text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg7TF.png).
```

Or other formats. If this is your thing, see [additional information on Markdown editing at SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).